# Compilation error with an throw used in an @:external inline abstract method

Tags: haxe

### The correction of this issue is simple : Update Haxe correctly to 3.2.0

In my case, something wrong happend during the update so it didn't work totally on 3.1.3.

---

I've encounter some troubles with compilation with this little piece of code :

```
interface MyInterface {
    public function getBits(pos:Int, size:Int, signed:Bool=false):Int;

    public function setBits(pos:Int, value:Int, size:Int, signed:Bool=false):Int;
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    public function new() {}

    public function getBits(pos:Int, size:Int, signed:Bool=false):Int Make.Unfinished("getBits");

    public function setBits(pos:Int, value:Int, size:Int, signed:Bool=false):Int Make.Unfinished("setBits");
}

enum AbstractError {
    Unfinished(name:String);
}

abstract Make(Void) {
    @:extern public inline static function Unfinished(name:String="") throw AbstractError.Unfinished(name);
}
```

This is a little version of my programm, who work on [this](http://try.haxe.org/#AA334) but doesn't when I compile for the Neko Runtime.
Actually, I receive this compile time error when I try to compile :

```
Void should be Int

Missing return Int
```

And that, for MyClass.getBits and MyClass.setBits ...
Have you any explanation for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked on GitHub, and have the answer, there was something wrong in my Haxe 3.2.0 installation, because it works on 3.2.0, so I've reinstall and it works now.

Thanks for the help and for the looking !

Answer (score 0):

I think that an extern method cannot/should not be marked as inline. Why do you do that? Does it work when you remove the `inline`?

Also, I notice you added an enum after the getBits and setBits function in MyClass. What is the purpose of that? Arent you missing a return statement these? If so, then the return type should be AbstractError.

Comment: I do this like this because of that : http://haxe.org/manual/class-field-inline.html

Originaly, I didn't use the `@:external`, but with the compilation error, I search and found that the @:external is theorically the solution, but actually it didn't.

The idea is that everything of the Make disapear, an simple optimisation. The class Make have some usage to emulate the abstract class of Java and unfinished feature on my libraries.

Comment: If it is inlined, then it is not visible in the output. That's why you maybe don't need the @:extern metadata.

Comment: Also abstract classes are different from abstract types. Haxe does not have abstract classes. It's uses a different concept. See http://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract.html

Comment: I know, it's why I make something to emulate the Java abtsract. ;) The abstract is a compile time feature. :) And with or without the @:external, it change nothing, it doesn't work, and, also, inlined is visible on the output, you know, but in an other and interisting way, with inline you can  make constant, for exemple. ;)

Comment: The "missing return int" is because the getBit does not return an actual int. It should have a return statement.

Comment: I think its not needed to have a abstract here. You can just use a class with static inline function.

Comment: To make it clear : `Make.Unfinished("getBits");` should be replace during compilation by that : `throw AbstractError.Unfinished("getBits");`, so the throw cut the program before any return, so the return is useless, or, during the compilation, he ask for the return, instead of passing that. Finally, the @:external have an using for the method who will be replace by a throw, to ensure the return error during compilation, but Neko don't like it apparently, the Try Haxe compilator accept it, avec without the @:external, so I'm lost, why a compilator work and the compilator on my computer don't ..

Comment: The abstract class for the Make is not the problem, I've try without, and for the sake of the optimisation, I will keep it, because it disapear after, because it's an Abstract Haxe Class. ;) I don't want an ghost class without any utilities neither any function, it would be a memory vaste. I prefer the use of a compile time class like the abstract, whe it possible, like here, it's why I've an abstract of a Void. :)